# can anyone translate this language please? what Language is it?

Tags: language-identification

[image: unknown language on image]

Can anyone please translate the text in this image please, I have no clue where to start?

Answer (score 6):

The language is Kazakh. It's a fragment of a poem by [*Шал (Тілеуке) Құлекеұлы*](https://kk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2i%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D2%9A%D2%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D2%B1%D0%BB%D1%8B) aka *Шал ақын* (1748 – 1819):

`Бұл дүниенің мысалы
Ұшып өткен құспен тең.
Өмірде көрген жақсылық
Ұйықтап өткен түспен тең.
Атадан мирас ақылың,
Түзік айтқан мақұлың,
Ләзім болған іспен тең.
Үлкеннен көрген зорлығың,
Жаманнан көрген қорлығың
Ойлап тұрсаң, бозбала,
Дұшпаннан көрген күшпен тең.
Ағайының көп болса,
Бірлігі оның бек болса,
Жамандық жер кез келсе,
Бір-біріне сеп болса,
Бүтін тұрған бұзылмай,
Отыз екі тіспен тең.`

That's how Google translates it:

`An example of this world
It is equal to the birds that fly.
Goodness in life
It is the same as sleeping color.
From the Father to Your Majesty,
The verdict,
It is equal to the pleasure.
Your aggression from the eldest,
It's a bad idea
Wait, boy,
Equal to the force seen by the enemy.
If he has a big brother,
If his unity is firm,
When a wicked person comes to an end,
If you sow each other,
Without a break,
Thirty-two teeth are equal.`

Here's the [audio](http://muslim.kz/uploads/kk/audio/839/bul-dunienin-mysaly-[audio]-shal-aqyn-qulekeuly.mp3) for the whole poem.

Comment: many thanks that's great!  will solve a puzzle for many people!

Comment: google translate to render (really the right word) poetry = a terrible idea.

Comment: @fdb - I don'ty speak Kazakh, what abou you? As far as I know Turkic languages, the google translate translation is adequate. What makes you think it's not?